# Extract and Format Site Data Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

This is for Python 3.5.x
What I'm looking for is to find the header, after a peice of the HTML code being

```
<h3 class = "title-link__title"><span class="title=link__text">News Here</span>

with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.bbc.co.uk/news') as r:
    HTML = r.read()
    HTML = list(HTML)
    for i in range(len(HTML)):
        HTML[i] = chr(HTML[i])
```

How can I get it so I extract just the header as that's all I need. I'll try and help for detail in anyway i can.

Comment: Have you tried using regex? Also, you might want to clarify specifically what you hope the program would extract from the above HTML.

Comment: Thanks but I've got it working using BeautifulSoup and I was looking for headers which would frequently change.

Answer (score 1):

Fetching information from webpages is called `web scraping`.

One of the best tools to do this job is the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

#opening page
r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.bbc.co.uk/news').read()
#creating soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

#useful for understanding the layout of your page info
#print soup.prettify()

#creating a ResultSet with all h3 tags that contains a class named 'title-link__title'
a = soup.findAll("h3", {"class":"title-link__title"})

#counting ocurrences
len(a)
#result = 44

#get text of first header
a[0].text
#result = u'\nMay v Leadsom to be next UK PM\n'

#get text of second header
a[1].text
#result = u'\nVideo shows US police shooting aftermath\n'
```